# Add multiple tabs and forms in backend of a custom module in magento just like customer backend porsitions

Tags: magento, module, tabs, magento-1.7, admin

**I have created a custom  extension just like a customer module and I want backend just like a customer.**

My extension has two tables and two models.
My modules are:

`Mage::getModel('custommod/reg')` - just like `Mage::getModel('customer/customer')`, reg saves data of registration

`Mage::getModel('custommod/personal')` - just like `Mage::getModel('customer/address')`, //personal data of a reg records.
Please check the image below:
[image]
**Now I am facing the problem to show the data  and edit .
In  Magento customer admin section, Customer edit position has multiple tabs: Account information, Address etc.**

Here, Account information tab saves data in customer/customer
and Address information tab saves data in customer/address.

I like this type of section.

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145237/magento-tabbed-backend-like-catalog-product-for-custom-entity/14151654#14151654

Comment: Amit,but issue  when i want to show the the data ,when i edit the tab...second data will save into other module....

Comment: In saveAction you can save the data to whichever table you want.. you must be getting all post data..

Comment: ok,thanks for your reply.....,I have already done it

Comment: If you have already done that then why you have not added your code...means how you done and all the stuff..that can help other people who visit this post and also if they like your answer you can get some upvotes too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After  a long time work i  have done it ,Here the solution
The tabs.php show left panel

```
<?php

class Amit_Vendor_Block_Adminhtml_List_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('vendor_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Manage Vendor'));
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->addTab('form_section', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('vendor')->__('General Information'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('vendor')->__('General Information'),
            'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('vendor/adminhtml_list_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
        ));



    $this->addTab('vendor_details',array(
                'label'=>Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Vendor Store  Details'),
                'title'=>Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Vendor Store  Details'),
                'content'=>$this->getLayout()->createBlock('vendor/adminhtml_list_edit_tab_storedetails')->toHtml(),

    ));
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

after the form.php

```
<?php

class Amit_Vendor_Block_Adminhtml_List_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $vendor = Mage::registry('vendor_data');
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(); 
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('vendor_form', array(
            'legend' => Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Vendor Registration')
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Name'),
            'required' => true,
        ));


        $fieldset->addField('email', 'text', array(
            'name'    => 'email',
            'label'   => Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Email'),
            'required' => true,

        ));
         $fieldset->addField('user_name', 'text', array(
            'name'    => 'user_name',
            'label'   => Mage::helper('vendor')->__('User name'),
            'required' => true,

        ));




        $fieldset->addField('password', 'password', array(
            'name'     => 'password',
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'label'    => Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Password'),
            'required' => true,
        ));

        $this->setForm($form);
        $form->setValues($vendor->getData());

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    public function filter($value)
    {
        return number_format($value, 2);
    }
}
```

Second form Storedetails.php

```
<?php
class Amit_Vendor_Block_Adminhtml_List_Edit_Tab_Storedetails extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form{
     protected function _prepareForm(){ 

        $vendorStore = Mage::registry('vendor_store_details');// new registry for different module
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(); 
        //$form->setFieldNameSuffix('vendor_store');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('vendor_form', array(
        'legend' => Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Vendor deatsilsn')
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('alternative_email','text',array(
            'name' =>'alternative_email',
            'label' => Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Alternative Email'),
            'required'=> false
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('shopname','text',array(
            'name' =>'shopname',
            'label' => Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Shop Name'),
            'required'=> true,
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('company', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'company',
        'label' => Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Company'),
        'required' => true,
         'class'     => 'required-entry',
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('street','text',array(
            'name' =>'vendor_details[street]',
            'label' => Mage::helper('vendor')->__('Street Address'),
            'required'=> false
        ));


        $this->setForm($form);
        $form->addValues($vendorStore->getData());
        return parent::_prepareForm();

        }


}
```